# C++ program infile won't open in xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, ifstream

[alt text http://img638.imageshack.us/img638/5731/screenshot20100613at121.png](http://img638.imageshack.us/img638/5731/screenshot20100613at121.png)

Why does the c++ program produce the error shown?  I'm especially confused since outfile opens without error yet infile displays the error?  Both are defined in xcode exactly the same!!  I've altering the "path type" setting without success.  The open on infile always fails!  Any suggestions  would be very much appreciated!!

For those who responded thanks but as you can see but infile and outfile exist and are in the same location:

[alt text http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/9316/screenshot20100613at123.png](http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/9316/screenshot20100613at123.png)

Comment: Do not post bitmaps containing error messages - copy and paste the errors and the code as text.

Comment: @neil, just out of curiosity why?

Comment: Because your screenshot is way too low-res to read.  BTW out_file is 30 minutes older than in_file, so it probably isn't the copy of out_file your program is actually writing to.

Comment: @Ben all you need to do is view image to get high res.....its much easier and gives more information than typing all of that in.  Plus it prevents errors from creeping into the question and therefore saves time for people responding.  I mean they allow embedded images for a reason right?

Comment: Your 500000 bytes picture contains 300 bytes data which we need to answer your question. These 300 characters are easily copy and pastable into the question.
Apart from this, the first image contains way too much non useful information, e.g. white areas. In fact, you realized that yourself and added yet another picture.

To sum it up, posting a picture is just an expression of laziness and an insult to those who would want to try your code to give you an answer.

Comment: It's much easier for you, but everybody looking at the question has to do additional work to view the picture properly. A time that could otherwise have been spent on trying to solve your problem. If you want to embed pictures please make sure they are displayed readable, because otherwise the whole embedding is useless.

Comment: @nusi 1. laziness is the first essential character trait of a good developer 2. why do they allow embedded images? 3. down voting my question displays both immaturity and insecurity......

Comment: @ sth oh please, wasting time?  simply "view image" takes what 1/2 second?  Thats much less than can be wasted answering an incorrectly inputted question!  Also no one has answer why embedded images are allowed!!!  I mean come on!  I've seen people constantly complain that not enough information is given by the questioner and now you complaning that I gave you too much???

Comment: @ennuikiller: I'm saying if you embed an image, do it in a way so that it is shown readably. Then you could, for example, look at the source code and your description of the problem at the same time. The whole point of embedding a picture is lost if you can read anything on the embedded version of the picture.

Comment: @sth but a simple "view image" is all that is needed! I still don't see the tremendous effort required to do that!

Comment: @ennuikiller; If laziness is indeed an "essential character trait" of a programmer, I'm going to be a good programmer and skip over the question of someone who has been told how to improve on his question but will fight back instead of being thankful. I'm too lazy to even try to decipher those bitmaps.

Comment: @ennuikiller: The point of embedding is to see the image immediately, else a simple link would do. If I do "view image" I have to constantly switch tabs when reading your description and comparing it to the source code and when answering and comparing the answer to the source code/error message (after figuring out that Ctrl-"View Image" actually opens it in a new tab). Also, if I would need to quote something from the source code I'd have to retype it instead of being able to copy&paste.

Comment: @sth you will see that almost all my questions do not have images...the reason I choose to do so in this question is precisely that I didn't need to include any other info...that is you do not need to switch back and forth...also it is interesting to note that all the time wasting on reprimanding me for using embedded images is way more than it would have required for viewing the image!!

Comment: @ennuikiller: And don't forget the time I wasted on answering your question.

Comment: @sth thanks a lot I'll be sure to tell all of my colleagues what a wonderful bunch of folks hang out on stackoverflow!!  You reminded me why I haven't been active on this site for so long........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In Xcode, expand the "Targets" node and find your target. Given what I've seen, it'll be the only one there.
2. Next, right-click on your project and add a new "Copy Files" build phase. When the dialog box comes up, make sure you set the Destination to "Products Directory".
3. The new build phase will appear beneath your target with whatever name you gave it. Drag your in_file and out_file there.
4. Compile and run.

Comment: Thank you Gregory, you've restored my faith in StackOverflow!!

Comment: My pleasure. This is pretty basic Xcode stuff, so I'm surprised that someone hadn't answered it before me!

Comment: As you can see they would prefer to chastise me for using embedded images!!

Comment: True, but at least you've learned now not to do it. I do think there are rare cases where an image is helpful, but not with plain code.

Comment: Well here's the thing, in one image I was able to show the code, the console output and the project structure.  To me that worth whatever downside an embedded image brings (which so far no one has been able to elucidate).  So you have to open the image to get high res, so what?  In the age of 4gb memory laptops, this is not a problem!!  For this question, as you can see, there was no need to cut & paste the code, so again please tell me what major infraction have i committed by including this image??

Comment: @ennuikiller To me it's not a big deal about the images. I don't think the size of the images is the problem. The problem is that the images are hosted somewhere other than StackOverflow. ImageShack, to be specific. One of the purposes of SO is to help other people, not just the questioner. Years from now, this question might help another developer with this very problem, but if the images no longer display, it may be harder for that person to figure out what's going on. I try to avoid external resources when using SO.

Comment: Thank you VERY much for an intelligent answer that makes sense, instead of, like the other responders, just chastising me and down-voting!  Now the question I have is why allow embedded images at all then?

Comment: @ennuikiller I agree. I think they should not be allowed.

Answer (score 2):

In your current case `out_file` would be created even if it doesn't exist (because you're using `std::ofstream`).

`in_file`, on the other hand, has to exist, and *(I guess there is no such file in the directory with created binary)*, hence an error is produced.

*Did you try launching your compiled application with the file in the same folder where the binary file is?*

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is no file named "in_file" in the program's working directory, so it can't be opened for reading.

For `outfile` this doesn't matter since it is opened for writing and if it doesn't exist yet it will just be created.

The directory listing you posted doesn't show where the compiled executable is, but probably it will be somewhere in the `build` directory. Probably this is then also its working directory and the place where the input file would need to be. (Look for the `out_file` the program creates when it is run, it will be created in the working directory, the same directory where it searches for `in_file`. And it is not the directory you posted the listing of, the `out_file` there is too old.)

Comment: but shouldn't there be a way of putting it in the cwd directly in the xcode project?

Comment: If you do a Get Info on your executable in Xcode you will see that you can set the default working directory to anything you like. Having said that, your program shouldn't be making any assumptions about working directory anyway, since it can be set to anything when you're app is launched.

Comment: yes the program should not
 make any assumptions about locations, I was just trying to do this for convenience....

Comment: I think its ok if a "hello world" program makes some assumptions that wouldn't be best practice in a real program.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you have to specifically create the file here:

Project Path/build/Debug

apparently you can't just define it directly in the xcode project